# How to give admin rights to another account for specific application

Tags: c++, windows, installation, driver, administrator

I created a driver setup using install shield.When I install and communicate with it as an administrator, everything is working fine.

**But on the customer site having some limited access on the system, driver is not communicating as expected. So I would like to know that how can I provide admin privilege for this particular driver on the another account. Because to give admin rights for all applications to limited account is not a suitable way.**

So please guide me in appropriate way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The proper way to do this is to include a manifest with your installer that requests elevation. Specifically, set the `requestedExecutionLevel` to `requireAdministrator` (rather than the default, `asInvoker`):

```
<requestedExecutionLevel level="requireAdministrator" uiAccess="false" />
```

This way, whenever a user running without elevated privileges launches the installer, Windows knows that the installer requires administrative privileges and automatically asks the user for valid credentials.

If the user can provide them, the installer is launched with administrative privileges, leaving other applications unaffected.

If the user cannot, the installer will fail to launch (which is fine, since it will fail anyway).

You can find more information on using manifests with UAC [here from Microsoft](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb756929.aspx).